# necesario especificar url en @html.beginform al utilizar $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una aplicación en MVC ASP.NET y he creado un formulario con ocho campos basado en un modelo, mi pregunta es esta:

Si quiero utilizar jQuery-AJAX-JSON en el evento click de mi botón submit para enviar mi modelo al controlador, significa entonces que no es necesario especificar la acción en el formulario creado a partir del modelo:

```
@Html.BeginForm("accion", "controller", FormMethod.Post
```

ya que se especifica en:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'acción/controller'
});
```

??? gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No, no es necesario dado que lo específicas en la llamada a `ajax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas `$.ajax` entonces no usas `@Html.BeginForm()`, o no es necesario, podrias simplemente usar un `<form id="form1">` y eso alcanza si es que quieres serializar el form para enviarlo en `$.ajax`

[Web API With AJAX: Submit Form Data After Serialization](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-submit-form-data-after-serialization/)

Analiza como hace uso del

```
$('#form1').serialize()
```

para enviar los datos por ajax, pero no necesitas el form que define el helper de mvc, puedes hacelro simplemente con el tag form de html.

Salvo que estes evaluando usar el [@Ajax.BeginForm()](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/0c1bb2/ajax-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) en ese caso si estarias implementando una llamada ajax usando el helper de mvc.